# How to disable ServiceStack sessions while keeping authentication features to implement per-request authentication

Tags: .net, authentication, servicestack, basic-authentication

I'm trying to force per request authentication, but by adding the `AuthFeature` the `SessionFeature` gets added automatically, which appears to cache the authentication result (I'm not getting multiple calls to `IUserAuthRepository.TryAuthenticate` across requests coming from the same client).

I've tried commenting out the `SessionFeature` being added in the `AuthFeature` but it doesn't seem to have an effect, a session is still created? Also, in the `AuthFeature` constructor I pass in null for the session factory, and still a session is created. I would expect this to either not create a session, or throw an exception? Anyway, I will continue to explore this area, but to make progress on this project I just need to know how to do per-request authentication with the built-in authentication providers?

Answer (score 1):

In our project we go to the simple way.

Create some thing in bellow.

Base Auth class:

```
 public class TagAuth
    {
        /// <remarks/>
        public string agent { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string sign { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        public string ts { get; set; }

        /// <remarks/>
        public int seed { get; set; }
    }
```

Base class for all request:

```
 public class BaseRequest
    {
        /// <remarks/>
        public TagAuth auth { get; set; }
    }
```

Use BaseRequest class for all request in model:

```
public class Cancel : BaseRequest
    {

        public long bid { get; set; }

    }
```

Implement ServiceInterface:

public class CancelService : ServiceBase
{

```
protected override object Run(Cancel request)
{
    SecurityManager.CheckAuthorization(request.auth); 
    return CancelRouter.Route(request);
}
```

}

But native support per-request auth is intresting for us too.